# Show/Hide on click with Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use a basic on click to expand so when the user clicks on the title it shows more details but for some reason it isn't working.

Here is the page in question:
http://eftposnz.wpengine.com/integrated-eftpos/pos-vendors/

I'm not sure if the issue is with the code itself or if I'm not using it correctly.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".content").hide();
    $(".show_hide").on("click", function () {
        var txt = $(".content").is(':visible') ? 'Read More' : 'Read Less';
        $(".show_hide").text(txt);
        $(this).next('.content').slideToggle(50);
      show_hide.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and please let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: is there any error in the console? are you adding the elements dynamically?

Comment: The console says, `$` is not a function. For some reason, jQuery has not been interpreted yet, when your script at the bottom of the page is executed. Which is odd though

Comment: Thank you for your fast help everybody. Problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site is currently using wordpress, so there is not "$" defined in the window context, instead of this, is only avalible via "jQuery".

A solution can be:

```
(function($){

$(function(){
   /* Here your code */
});

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with WordPress, but it seems like the jQuery version it's using (or that you chose to use) won't let you use `$` from the get-go.

As you can see on the [jQuery version included on your page](http://eftposnz.wpengine.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4), [`jQuery.noConflict()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) is called at the end, making `$` unavailable.

Here's what you can do, as an easy/safe workaround:

```
(function($) {

  // your code using $ here

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery is known in the window's scope as `jQuery` instead of `$`, which is a result of `jQuery.noConflict()`.
Now you could create `$` yourself by writing this above your code:

```
var $ = jQuery; // yuck!
```

**But that would pollute your global scope!!**

It would be cleaner to wrap your code into an anonymous function like this:

```
(function ($) {
  // your code
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Kim.

Comment: Glad it helped, Josh. I like the page you're making, it looks fancy yet clean. Cheers!